# What subtitle file editor for '.srt' files supports synchronization?

Tags: windows, video, software-rec, editing, subtitles

I downloaded `.srt` files for watching a French movie. But unfortunately, it is out of sync.
Is there any tool in Windows using which I could manually sync it specifying the start time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) also lets you add (or subtract) subtitle delay so you can sync them up while viewing.  Ctrl-H and Ctrl-J shift the delay by 50ms in either direction.

SRT files are basic text files, so once you've found an offset that looks right in VLC, use perl or sed (or your favorite scripting language) to add that offset to all the timecodes in the file.

(Or try the aforementioned subtitle editor programs if you're not up for the challenge of off-the-cuff timecode math.)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Subtitle Workshop](http://www.urusoft.net/products.php?cat=sw). I can recommend version 2.51, haven't tried the new beta.

Another editor for subtitles is [Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/).

Comment: Neither http://www.urusoft.net nor http://blog.aegisub.net are found.

Comment: I fixed link for Aegisub, as for urusoft link, it works ok for me

Answer (score 5):

I strictly recommend [**Subtitle Edit**](http://www.nikse.dk/SubtitleEdit).

> Features:
>
> - **Visually sync/adjust a subtitle (start/end position and speed).**
> - Create/add subtitle lines
> - Translation helper (for manual translation)
> - Convert between SubRib, MicroDVD, Substation Alpha, SAMI, and more
> - Import VobSub sub/idx binary subtitles (code is ripped from
>     Subtitle Creator by Erik
>     Vullings/Manusse)
> - Can read and write UTF-8 and other unicode files (besides ANSI)
> - Show texts earlier/later
> - Merge/split
> - Adjust display time
> - Fix common errors wizard
> - Remove text for hear impaired
> - Renumbering
> - Swedish to danish translation built-in (via Multi Translator Online)
> - Google translation built-in
> - Spell checking via Open Office dictionaries/NHunspell (many
>     dictionaries available)
> - Effects: Typewriter and karoake
> - Can open subtitles embedded inside matroska files
> - History/undo manager

Answer (score 4):

These are so many best subtitle editor . but it dependents on   what the other features you are looking from the sub title editors.

[***Jubler***](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jubler/) is a subtitle editor which can work with *.SUB and *.SRT files. Jubler lets you join, split, and recode into different frame rates, delete and remove depending on specific patterns, and edit specific subtitles in place.

[image]

***or***

[DVDSubedit](http://download.videohelp.com/DVDSubEdit/) (free)

***or***

Go to www.videohelp.com/tools and search for srt . Find the one as you like

Comment: was a snap to install on OSX and easily edited my first subtitle file and recoded the original framerate to the movie's framerate. nice, simple software. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Manually? You can open the .srt file in Notepad (or your favourite alternative) and edit the time codes.

Maybe you need to add the time lag amount to all the time codes. I believe that [Media Player Classic](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/) can "shift" the subtitles forward or back, but while you are viewing.

I also think I came across some external software to edit the times automatically. Let me know if this is what you want and I'll try to find them.

Answer (score 0):

Subtitle Workshop has already been recommended to you (+1!)

However, if you don't want to go that way, play your subtitled movie with **[SMPlayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/)** (a multiplatform front-end for **mplayer**). It's the best all-round media player when it comes to subtitle handling and options (by a far cry!)

[image]

*SMPlayer is open source, freeware and a portable version is available as well.*

On a personal note, SMPlayer beats the highly overrated VLC player hands down.

Answer (score 0):

the best thing is change the file extension from .srt to .txt. Then complete your editing and change it back to .srt. This will surely help. and to play it with the move simply change the srt files name same as the video file but do not remove the .srt extension from the subtitle file..

Comment: Why do you have to change the file extension? Just drag the file onto Notepad...