# How do you edit a .srt (Subtitles)?

Tags: editing, subtitles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is the best subtitle file editor (srt)?](https://superuser.com/questions/49245/which-is-the-best-subtitle-file-editor-srt)

I have ripped my Kill Bill DVD's but the Japanese parts aren't subtitled in English...  I found some subtitles online but the only ones which seem to work are the ones for the entire movie.  I want to edit the srt file so that the only parts left are the ones where they actually speak Japanese.

How would I go about doing this?  What program can I use, and how easy is it to edit?

Also, I'd like to hard code the file after so that I never have to worry about the srt's again.

Comment: Potential duplicate : http://superuser.com/questions/49245/which-is-the-best-subtitle-file-editor-srt

Comment: This is not a duplicate!  Please re-open.  I'm specifically trying to figure out how to edit the .srt so that I can get rid of subtitles.  I'm not asking how to sync the file with my video!

Comment: Which the duplicate question does provide. Did you even look at the answers on the duplicate?

Comment: It does not explain how to hard code a file with the subtitles.

Comment: Please see my comments on meta. I have locked the post to prevent further edits, and the second part of this question should be asked as a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strictly recommend [**Subtitle Edit**](http://www.nikse.dk/se/).

> Features:
>
> - Visually sync/adjust a subtitle (start/end position and speed).
> - Create/add subtitle lines
> - Translation helper (for manual translation)
> - Convert between SubRib, MicroDVD, Substation Alpha, SAMI, and more
> - Import VobSub sub/idx binary subtitles (code is ripped from
>     Subtitle Creator by Erik
>     Vullings/Manusse)
> - Can read and write UTF-8 and other unicode files (besides ANSI)
> - Show texts earlier/later
> - Merge/split
> - Adjust display time
> - Fix common errors wizard
> - Remove text for hear impaired
> - Renumbering
> - Swedish to danish translation built-in (via Multi Translator Online)
> - Google translation built-in
> - Spell checking via Open Office dictionaries/NHunspell (many
>     dictionaries available)
> - Effects: Typewriter and karoake
> - Can open subtitles embedded inside matroska files
> - History/undo manager

You can use [**VirtualDub**](http://virtualdub.sourceforge.net/) to hard code subtitles into video files. You can find the instructions [here](http://www.my-guides.net/en/content/view/154/44/).

Answer (score 0):

I've found an editor for you:

[SubCreator](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Encoders-Converter-DIVX-Related/SubCreator.shtml)

It was the first hit on Google for "srt subtitle editor" :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this with gedit as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SUBTITLE WORKSHOP 2.51](http://www.urusoft.net/download.php?lang=1&id=sw).

It's freeware and easy to use.You can split/combine/convert fps values in subtitles.It supports all subtitle formats and also you can create your owm extension.

Comment: simply the best ... +1