# How to perfectly synchronize Subtitles with movie?

Tags: windows-7, video, sync, vlc-media-player, subtitles

How to perfectly synchronize Subtitles with movie? i use VLC

Comment: What format are the subtitles and movie file? Is it a single MKV, OGG etc file with a subtitle stream or is it a separate .SRT, .IDX/.SUB,  .IDX/.RAR etc subtitle file(s)?

Comment: separate .SRT and I have many video in multiple formats

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**If the sync error remains constant then you have a delay issue.**

If you are using version 0.8.2 or above then keys <kbd>g</kbd> and <kbd>h</kbd> will allow you to adjust the sync delay during playback.

If your subtitles are appearing and disappearing too early then use <kbd>h</kbd> to increase the delay until they appear at the correct time.

If your subtitles are appearing and disappearing too late then use <kbd>g</kbd> to decrease the delay until they appear at the correct time.

**If the sync gets worse (gets more and more ahead or behind) as the playback progresses then you have a timing issue.**

This is usually due to a subtitle file being set up for a different frame rate than the video.

You will need to convert the subtitle file to match the frame rate of the video.

As you are using .SRT subtitle files there are some suggestions on tools to re-time them on this SuperUser question: [Which is the best subtitle file editor (srt)?](https://superuser.com/questions/49245/which-is-the-best-subtitle-file-editor-srt)

You can use [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) to check the frame rate of both video and subtitle files to help you decide which conversions are required on the subtitle files.

Comment: what if a bit of the video has been cut out (e.g. an intro cut short), so your subtitles are in sync before a particular point, but out of sync afterwards?

Comment: @Ashley either a) use subtitle aware software to make the cut so the problem doesn't happen in the first place or b) use the first option above, once the cut point is passed

Answer (score 3):

Try [**Easy Subtitles Synchronizer**](http://easysubs.blogspot.com/) (ESS). It is a freeware tool that creates, repairs and synchronizes your subtitles easily.

Comment: doesn't work with VLC 2, I didn't like it.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily change synchronization of your subtitles with any modern video player today. However, if you want to permanently setup synchronization you need to do it manually (hard way) or by using some specialized software.

Definitely my own favorite is [Subtitle Workshop](http://www.urusoft.net/downloads.php?lang=1), and through it you can do much more than just [sync your subtitle](http://video.tutsdb.com/2013/05/sync-subtitles.html). It supports practically every single subtitle format you may find and use today.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add an easy solution for the case **If the sync gets worse (gets more and more ahead or behind) as the playback progresses then you have a timing issue.**

Play the movie and seek to final minutes of the film(Helps in reducing the error)

1. Hear a dialog currently saying and press `pause` and note the
   time(This is the desired time)
2. Open the subtitle in a text editor and note the time of the same
   dialog in the file(This is the present time)
3. Go to "expand and narrow" section in
   http://subtitlefix.com/index.php Fill the form and leave `old fps`
   and `new fps` fields blank
4. Click `Send`
5. Save the correct file available for download and enjoy the movie :D

Answer (score 0):

There are many subtitle editors on Windows or Linux but they do more than synchronize, and therefore are rather complicated for the simple purpose of fitting a subtitle to a movie. Many video players can delay/change the time of the subtitle in order to synchronize it but not many are able to *save* that change.

The simplest way I know is [MPC-HC](https://mpc-hc.org/) in Windows. It is also very powerful. I have seen it fixing subtitles that were a nightmare to fix with a dedicated tool.

See this specific answer with all the details on how to  ["Use Media Player Classic to resynchronize subtitles"](https://superuser.com/a/573450/1039759).

[*I am the OP of that solution, posted under a now dead account.]

Quoting from there:

Start the movie and load the subtitle (<kbd>File</kbd> <kbd>Load Subtitle</kbd>)

Go to <kbd>View</kbd> <kbd>Subresync</kbd>.

Select a certain line in subtitle table and when the movie reaches that line
**pause** it.

Right click the <kbd>Time</kbd> value and click <kbd>Current</kbd>

[image]

Un-pause the movie to check the sub is synced.

<kbd>File</kbd> <kbd>Save Subtitle</kbd>; in case the new file is not loaded
immediately, restart the player with the new subtitle.