# Use Media Player Classic to resynchronize subtitles?

Tags: windows, video, subtitles, media-player-classic

I see that in  Media Player Classic, under ***View - Subresync***, there is a tool that should serve to resynchronize subtitles.

What is the procedure exactly?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Start the movie and load the subtitle (<kbd>File</kbd> <kbd>Load Subtitle</kbd>)

Go to <kbd>View</kbd> <kbd>Subresync</kbd>.

Select a certain line in subtitle table and when the movie reaches that line
**pause** it.

Right click the <kbd>Time</kbd> value and click <kbd>Current</kbd>

[image: subresync]

Un-pause the movie to check the sub is synced.

<kbd>File</kbd> <kbd>Save Subtitle</kbd>; in case the new file is not loaded
immediately, restart the player with the new subtitle.

---

NOTE the comments below, namely by @kajacx: ***"Or you can use F1 and F2 to sync the subtitles by 500ms, without opening the menu or pausing your video."***

Comment: +1 For nice answer. Just press `F5` to sync with the current position.

Comment: How can I apply this on all of the subtitles, not just that one line?

Comment: Or you can use `F1` and `F2` to sych the subtitles by 500ms, without opening the menu or pausing your video.

Comment: How can I adjust the frame rate to the movie (after sync the subs they loose sync after a few minutes)

Comment: I second on the question made above by Behdad: How to apply this timing on every line of that subtitle ? Can't see the use of changing a single line.

Comment: Thanks for saving my life buddy.