# How to convert any song lyrics into subtitle file?

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player, subtitles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is the best subtitle file editor (srt)?](https://superuser.com/questions/49245/which-is-the-best-subtitle-file-editor-srt)

For example

I have a Video of some song.
I downloaded the lyrics from a lyrics site. I want to play these lyrics along with song in properly synchronized way on video. like we play Subtitle of Movie in VLC.

[image]

Comment: @Gnoupi - my question is totally different. it's not "Which is the best subtitle file editor (srt)?"

Comment: your question is "how to take text and match it to a video". It's the same as editing subtitles in my opinion. Nothing will do the job for you to put the lyrics on the good place. The answers given are all recommending you subtitle editors. This is why I closed it as duplicate, to avoid duplicating answers.

Answer (score 2):

**AegiSub** is an excellent subtitle tool.
It has specialized Karaoke features.
It handles Unicode, and is well documented, **and is free**.

- http://www.aegisub.org/

This Kanji Timer video wil give you some idea of its abilities.

- [Kanji-Timer.avi](http://www.animereactor.dk/aegisub/demovids/kanji-timer.avi)

Setting up timed subtitles is a time consuming job, no matter which program you use.
    **You** are the only "tool" which can identify the correct timing.

---

Answer (score 1):

Try [Subtitle Edit](http://www.nikse.dk/se/):

> Subtitle Edit is a free (open source) editor for video subtitles - a
>   subtitle editor :)
>
> With SE you can easily adjust a subtitle if it is out of sync with the
>   video in several different ways. You can also use SE for making new
>   subtitles from scratch (do use the time-line/waveform/spectrogram) or
>   translating subtitles.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [Subtitle Workshop](http://www.urusoft.net/products.php?cat=sw&lang=1)

> Subtitle Workshop is the most complete, efficient and convenient freeware subtitle editing tool. It supports all the subtitle formats you need and has all the features you would want from a subtitle editing program. Subtitle Workshop makes subtitle creating/editing/converting tasks almost a pleasure, the amicable and intuitive interface mixes easy to access menus & must have features with advanced functions and a remarkable speed and stability, drastically reducing subtitle editing time. It includes spell check function and an advanced video preview feature which will ease the task even more. The best choice for the beginner, expert or the fansubber. Have a try, and you'll forget the rest!