# MKV to MP4 with hardcoded subs (how can I delay subtitles?)

Tags: video, mp4, matroska, avidemux

I read on another question here on superuser that for converting from MKV to MP4 and hardcoding subs i have to use mkvextract and avidemux, i tried to do it, and basically it worked but... the subtitles are about 20ms before the video, there's some way to put delay on the subtitles?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if you can shift subtitles that have already been placed in video stream?
Look into [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/494841/how-can-i-fix-delayed-subtitles-in-videos) which basically states that it is not possible.

Comment: No, i have the .ass files and the raw videos, i have to put the subtitles on the video, but i can't match the timing cause i should have to delay the subs, and i don't know how should i do it

Comment: I believe this program can do what you need:
[Subtitle Edit](https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/releases/tag/3.4.6)
This guide should also help you:
[Ehow](http://www.ehow.com/how_12211824_edit-sub-timing.html)

Comment: that should do, anyway if i extracted the subtitles from a mkv where they was placed with the right timing, why they have the wrong timing after rejoining them with video?

Comment: Do you mean that whenever you hardcode the subtitles their sync changes? That must have something to do with the program you use. I cannot really tell you exactly what causes this issue as I am not sure what you have used.

Comment: i wrote it, i used mkvextract to get subtitles, then avidemux to hardcode them

Comment: if you are using ubuntu [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/106259/what-apps-to-sync-movie-subtitles-easily-are-available-for-ubuntu/106261#106261) might help you.
There is also similar thread in [here](http://avidemux.org/smuf/index.php?topic=12091.0).