# How to change offset of EIA-608 subtitles in an MP4?

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

I have an MP4 file containing H.264 Video, AAC Audio, and EIA-608 Closed Captions:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:11:26.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4952 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], Closed Captions, 4818 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

However, the subtitles are displaying about 2 seconds too early.

The catch is, as you can see, ffmpeg doesn't recognize `eia_608` as a "stream" that can be manipulated with the `-map` commands (as in [this question](https://superuser.com/a/1242613/165335)). So inputting the file multiple times to remux the subtitles back in with a delay gives the following error:

```
Stream map '1:s' matches no streams.
To ignore this, add a trailing '?' to the map.
```

And obviously `-itsoffset` affects the video exactly as much as the subtitles in every case, anyway.

#### So how do I add a slight delay to `eia_608` subtitles in an MP4 file without recoding?

Comment: And before anyone brings it up, I personally _love_ MKV, but now is not the time for that. In this situation, I need to leave the files as physically identical to their originals as possible, but adding a ~2s delay to the captions.

Comment: This may be possible. Can you upload a short sample?

Comment: You would need to remove the SEI’s from the AVC and write them back to a later frame, being careful to adjust for b frames. I don’t know any software that can do this. Maybe adobe premier or something.